# Who is who in solidity?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Contract {
    address payable public owner;
    address payable public charity;

    constructor(address payable _charity) {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        charity = _charity;
    }

    receive() external payable { }

    function donate() public {
        charity.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function tip() public payable {
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

msg.sender is the person deploys the contract

charity is charity

address(this) is contract address

When I use donate function "msg.value" sent to charity from owner ? But I use **address(this).balance** in this function. I dont use owner.

I dont understand what is happened when I use tip function ?

Comment: When you call `donate()` it sends from contract balance into charity address. When you call `tip()` you have to set some ETH to be sent to contract, that amount of ETH is `msg.vlue` and it will be sent to `owner` address so if you use owner wallet to call `tip()` you do not actually do anything

Answer (score 1):

The `donate()` function sends all the ETH of the contract to the address specified in the `charity` var.

The `tip()` function requires you to send ETH with your transaction. This is then transferred to the address specified in the `owner` var.

So if you are calling `tip()` from the owner address you are creating a tx which sends ETH to yourself.